# Building custom java config annotations - similar to custom XML namespaces

Tags: java, spring, spring-java-config

We're building a framework on top of Spring & Spring MVC. Our framework is quite mature at this point - about 2 years old and is used widely within our organization. Our framework is very modular (much like spring itself is). There are various modules that can be used independently or together. When used together they provide many benefits to the end user. We have built a handful custom spring XML namespaces (NamespaceHandlers, BeanDefinitionParsers, etc). Each module provides their own which brings in its own set of XML configuration elements. This is all working great for us and has been a really big win for us.

What we'd like to do now is move away from XML-based configuration and into java config. My idea/thought is for each module to introduce a set of java config annotations that can be used (something similar to the `@EnableCaching`, `@EnableMBeanExport` annotations). My question is this - even if I create my annotations - how do I "wire" them in so that if they are present I can do "stuff"? This would be similar conceptually to the NamespaceHandlers & BeanDefinitionParsers. I can't find any documentation anywhere as to how to get started.

I've thought about creating some custom abstract base classes which do what I need them to do - but the problem is when it comes to the end user's application - they can only extend a single class. I need a flexible way for each module in my framework to expose its own custom configuration that end user applications can use, just like they use our XML namespace elements.

Here's a glimpse as to what we do in XML (not full application context file - just a blurb from it pertaining to our custom XML namespaces):

```xml
<atom-web:web/>
<atom-web:logging/>
<atom-web:security entitlementsProvider="XML" xmlRefreshInterval="${cache.refresh.interval.ms}"/>

<atom-profile:profile caching="IN_MEMORY" entryExpiryDelay="${cache.refresh.interval.ms}"/>

<atom-prefs:preferences backingStoreUrl="${pref.backingStore.url}"/>

<atom-content:content contentServerBaseUrl="${content.server.url}" contentServerFileUrl="${content.server.file.url}" site="${site.name}" contentTaskExecutor="contentTaskExecutor" snippetCaching="IN_MEMORY" cacheRefreshInterval="${cache.refresh.interval.ms}"/>

<bean id="contentTaskExecutor" class="org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ThreadPoolTaskExecutor" p:corePoolSize="3" p:maxPoolSize="20"/>
```

What I'm envisioning is some kind of set of annotations - something like this:

```java
@EnableAtomWebApplication
@EnableAtomWebLogging
@EnableAtomWebSecurity(entitlementsProvider=EntitlementsProvider.XML, xmlRefreshDelay=120000)
@EnableAtomProfile(caching=CachingType.IN_MEMORY, expiryDelay=120000)
// Other annotations for rest of modules
@Configuration
public class ConfigurationClass {
   // Rest of configuration in here
}
```

Any help here would be greatly appreciated. I'm not quite sure where to start and can't really find any documentation anywhere to help me get started.

Answer (score 4):

So after thinking about this a bit I think I've found the correct starting point. I wanted to throw this out there for anyone who might be able to say "yeah thats the right place" or "no you aren't looking in the correct place".

Using my example above

```
@EnableAtomProfile(caching=CachingType.IN_MEMORY, expiryDelay=120000)
```

I would create an annotation for the @EnableAtomProfile annotation like this:

```
@Retention(value=java.lang.annotation.RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Target(value={java.lang.annotation.ElementType.TYPE})
@Documented
@Import({AtomProfileBeanDefinitionRegistrar.class})
public @interface EnableAtomProfile {
  CachingType caching() default CachingType.NONE;
  long expiryDelay default 0;
}
```

The AtomProfileBeanDefinitionRegistrar class would implement [org.springframework.context.annotation.ImportBeanDefinitionRegistrar](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/context/annotation/ImportBeanDefinitionRegistrar.html) and do any of the necessary stuff that I'm currently doing in my [BeanDefinitionParser](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/4.0.x/javadoc-api/org/springframework/beans/factory/xml/BeanDefinitionParser.html)

Comment: Your hint about implementing a custom `ImportBeanDefinitionRegistrar` just saved me hours of frustration - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can have a `BeanPostProcessor` defined, which would basically:

- inspect every single bean created
- with reflection check if the object's class is annotated with `@YourAnnotation`
- and if it is, then apply some custom logic - e.g. package the object into some other class or something

Reference:

1. [Spring docs on BeanPostProcessors](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/3.1.x/spring-framework-reference/htmlsingle/spring-framework-reference.html#beans-factory-extension-bpp)
2. [source code for `RequiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor`, which is a `BeanPostProcessor` which analyzes annotations](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-framework/blob/master/spring-beans/src/main/java/org/springframework/beans/factory/annotation/RequiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java)

Comment: That may work - but it doesn't really "feel" like the correct solution. Doesn't really have any "tie" whatsoever to `@Configuration` classes. There has to be some way within Spring to tie into `@Configuration` classes to add your own custom annotations or processing - just like Spring has support for custom XML namespaces - its built right into the framework.

Comment: Actually the more I think of it the more I realize this won't work. Using a `BeanPostProcessor` would be too late in the lifecycle. The purpose of the config classes/bean definition parsers is to be able to dynamically create and add new beans into the application context. If you're in a bean and executing inside a bean post processor then it is too late to introduce new bean definitions into the context.

Comment: Oh, sorry. I might've misunderstood. I thought that these annotations are meant to tweak the configuration of existing beans, not to cause some new beans to be created.

Comment: No worries - your response did make me think about it a bit. I appreciate the response!